# Normal distribution analog for HSV colour space

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, estimation, multivariate-normal-distribution, circular-statistics

[This question inspired by work by Jason Thornton et al (see https://cryptome.org/2012/05/person-large-area-spy.pdf , Equation (4))]

I am interested in modelling a distribution over the HSV color space (basically $[0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,2\pi)$ with wraparound for the final angular component): given sampled colour measurements, I would like to estimate the parameters for the distribution.  Are there known/studied classical distributions applicable to this space (or on $R^2\times S^1$), for which we know how to estimate parameters sensibly?

[Besides following the approach by Thornton, it seems one can embed the HSV data into a 4-dimensional space, by using ideas from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities, and then building and possibly marginalizing a 4-dimensional Gaussian, but I'd like to know if there is a better approach known, rather than devising ad-hoc approaches unnecessarily.]

Comment: I think you need to provide many more details before this can be answered.  The topology of the space is practically irrelevant and does not determine much of anything statistically.  What *could* matter--although it's unclear how relevant it is to color spaces--is the *group* structure of the space.  The sense in which you seek an "analog" of the Normal distribution would still be unclear: is it the stable distribution of the Central Limit Theorem or is it a distribution giving rise to linear solutions of Maximum Likelihood equations or is it merely a good description of measurement errors?

Comment: I'm simply interested in building a sensible parametric model of a distribution from samples in this space.  I don't know of a sensible group structure for the space.  I would expect the distribution to be peaked about a single mode, but otherwise I do not know too much about it.  So in some sense the only analogy to normality I really *require* is that it is an established unimodal distribution for the space for which we can estimate parameters from data, and which has parameters allowing one to adjust location and scale.  Being (something like) radially symmetric would also be nice.